# What does 鉢の木帯 mean?

Tags: meaning

> ――野武士か？　とは、すぐ思ったことだったが、意外にもそれはまだやっと十三、四歳にしかなるまいと思われる小娘であって襤褸てはいるが金襴らしい幅のせまい**鉢の木帯**をしめ、袂のまるい着物を着ているのである。――そしてその小娘もまた此方の人影をいぶかるものの如く、死骸と死骸との間から、迅こい猫のような眸を、じっと、射向けているのであった。｛宮本武蔵（1935年–1939年、朝日新聞連載、吉川英治）｝

What does it mean? (e.g. a kind of belt? if so, what kind of belt?)

Comment: Im not 100% sure but i think 鉢の木帯 is 鉢の木 + 帯 where 鉢の木 is a town near 鎌倉市 (かまくら し) in 神奈川県 (かながわ けん)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find this entry in any bilingual dictionary, and of the monolingual Japanese dictionaries I have access to, only my big dead-tree dictionary has this.

Shogakukan's [国語大辞典]{こくごだいじてん} ("Big Japanese Dictionary") has an entry for [鉢]{はち}の[木]{き}, explaining that this basically means a 木 (tree) in a 鉢 (pot), like a bonsai.  At the bottom of this entry, we get this:

> **鉢の木の帯（おび）**　黒地に梅・桜・松の模様を金で織りあげた女帯。
>   **Potted tree *obi***: a woman's *obi* with a woven design of plum trees, cherry trees, and pine trees in gold on a black background.

An *obi* is the wide fancy belt or sash used in formal kimono.  Read more about *obi* at [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obi_(sash)).

So that first sentence of your text above is basically describing the appearance of the 小娘{こむすめ}.

Comment: Downvoter, please comment to suggest improvements.

Comment: Irrelevant to downvoting, do you mean 日本国語大辞典 by 国語大辞典?

Comment: @broccoliforest, it's this one: 国語大辞典（新装版）小学館 1988.

Comment: Oh, I see. I found the 国語大辞典 from 尚学図書, but I didn't know it's affiliated with 小学館.